# PHP undefined index cuando un formulario esta vacio

Tags: php, html, poo

estoy aprendiendo PHP. De a poco voy avanzando. Cuando abro un formulario para probarlo **LA PRIMERA VEZ** me tira este error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: nombreFruta in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 23
Notice: Undefined index: colorFruta in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 24
```

Lo que yo quiero hacer es que cuando un formulario este vacio diga "algunos campos estan incompletos".
Ahora bien, cuando completo el formulario una vez, a la siguiente que no mando nada, funciona perfectamente. Pero la primera vez que se abre la pagina me tira el error que marque ahi arriba. Por que puede ser?

```
 <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nombreFruta" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nombre" required>
        <input type="text" name="colorFruta" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Color" required>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Cambiar el texto!</button>
    </form>


    <?php 
    include("frutas.php");
    

    $nombreFruta = $_POST['nombreFruta'];
    $colorFruta = $_POST['colorFruta'];

    if($nombreFruta  == "" || $colorFruta == "" ){
        echo "Algunos campos estan incompletos";
    }else{
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $manzana = new Fruta(true, $colorFruta, $nombreFruta);
            $asd = ("La " . $manzana->nombre  . $manzana->chequeaSiEsFruta(true) . "y es de color: $manzana->color ");
            echo $asd;
        }
    }
```

Aqui les dejo un link para que lo vean "en vivo":
http://federico-test.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Te faltan los `id` en los `inputs`

Comment: @Bicho los IDs sirven para la parte JS. Cuando se envía el formulario lo que valen son los *name*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te está ocurriendo eso ya que cuando la página carga estas igualando las variables a elementos que no están definidos, si usas `isset($variable)` para validar que la variable esté seteada o no podrías evitarlo, algo así:

```
if(isset($_POST['nombreFruta'])){
    $nombreFruta = $_POST['nombreFruta'];
}

if(isset($_POST['colorFruta'])){
    $colorFruta = $_POST['colorFruta'];
}
```

Con esto unicamente asignara las variables `$nombreFruta` y `$colorFruta` en caso que se hayan enviado mediante `POST`.

El caso del mensaje es similar, solo que en este caso añadimos `!` para validar que **NO** están seteadas, seria algo asi:

```
if(!isset($nombreFruta) || !isset($colorFruta)){
        echo "Algunos campos están incompletos";
    }else{
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $manzana = new Fruta(true, $colorFruta, $nombreFruta);
            $asd = ("La " . $manzana->nombre  . $manzana->chequeaSiEsFruta(true) . "y es de color: $manzana->color ");
            echo $asd;
        }
    }
```

Ojala sea lo que buscas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Gracias por responder! La solucion fue asignarles valor global a las variables, y declarar un isset que checkee si están llenos los input:

```
   if(isset($_POST["nombreFruta"]) && isset($_POST["colorFruta"])){
       $nombreFruta = $_POST["nombreFruta"];
       $colorFruta = $_POST["colorFruta"];
   }
   
   global $nombreFruta;
   global $colorFruta;
```

El código completo seria:

```
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <title>Documentos</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>

<body>

   <form action="" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="nombreFruta" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nombre">
       <input type="text" name="colorFruta" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Color">
       <button type="submit" name="submit">Cambiar el texto!</button>
   </form>


   <?php 
   include("frutas.php");
   
   if(isset($_POST["nombreFruta"]) && isset($_POST["colorFruta"])){
       $nombreFruta = $_POST["nombreFruta"];
       $colorFruta = $_POST["colorFruta"];
   }
   
   global $nombreFruta;
   global $colorFruta;


   if($nombreFruta == null || $colorFruta == null ){
       echo "Algunos campos estan incompletos";
   }else{
       if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
           $manzana = new Fruta(true, $colorFruta, $nombreFruta);
           $asd = ("La " . $manzana->nombre  . $manzana->chequeaSiEsFruta(true) . "y es de color: $manzana->color ");
           echo $asd;
       }
   }
   

?>






   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Deberías marcar como correcta (marca de check al lado de la puntuación) la respuesta que consideres como tal. Si has llegado a tu solución a través de la respuesta de Josue tocaría que marcaras la suya, si no es así/consideras que es muy diferente puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como correcta.

Comment: Gracias! No sabia. Ahora lo marco, me sirvió de ayuda para guiarme